# How to call function in server.r from ui.r

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, personality-insights

## Server.r

Text Analytics into big 5 personality traits(O,C,E,A,N)

Here I want the text to process when the user clicks Update View button.
Then that text will be stored in "sentence" variable, then cleaning the corpus, loading the wordlist files for each of the personality trait, matching th etex input with wordlist, summing the personality scores & displaying the score & the trait user has scored high

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
#Analysing text entered by the user 
function(input, output,session) {
textAnalysis <- eventReactive(input$update,{
  function(textdata){
  sentence <- input$textdata
  word.list <- str_split(sentence,"\\s+")
  words <- unlist(word.list)
  sentence <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', "", sentence) #gsub is global substitution from stringr library
  sentence <- gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', "", sentence) #cntrl are control words
  sentence <- gsub('\\d+', "", sentence)        #d is substituting digits with null
  sentence <- tolower(sentence)
  #Include word list in environment
  o.words = scan("F:/MTech_Project/OpenEnd/OpennessWordList.txt", what='character',comment.char = ";")
  c.words = scan("F:/MTech_Project/OpenEnd/ConscientiousnessWordList.txt", what='character',comment.char = ";")
  e.words = scan("F:/MTech_Project/OpenEnd/ExtraversionWordList.txt", what='character',comment.char = ";")
  a.words = scan("F:/MTech_Project/OpenEnd/AgreeablenessWordList.txt", what='character',comment.char = ";")
  n.words = scan("F:/MTech_Project/OpenEnd/NeuroticismWordList.txt", what='character',comment.char = ";")
  o.matches <- match(words,o.words)
  c.matches <- match(words,c.words)
  a.matches <- match(words,e.words)
  e.matches <- match(words,a.words)
  n.matches <- match(words,n.words)
  o.matches <- !is.na(o.matches)
  c.matches <- !is.na(c.matches)
  e.matches <- !is.na(e.matches)
  a.matches <- !is.na(a.matches)
  n.matches <- !is.na(n.matches)
  o.score <- sum(o.matches)
  #o.score
  c.score <- sum(c.matches)
  #c.score
  e.score <- sum(e.matches)
  #e.score
  a.score <- sum(a.matches)
  #a.score
  n.score <- sum(n.matches)
  #n.score
  score <- max(o.score,c.score,e.score,a.score,n.score)
  return(score)
  }}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


  output$value <- renderPrint({
    textdata <- textAnalysis()

    })

}
```

## Ui.r

Here I am trying to take text input from the user & calling "value" in server.r

```
library(shiny)
fluidPage(

  # Application title.
  titlePanel("Text Analytics"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(



    textInput("textdata",label = "Tell something about you..what you are..what you like",""),

      actionButton("update", "Update View")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("value"),  
    )))
```

I am stuck with how to pass the text to server.r & how to get the result displayed in ui.r Please help

## Console Result

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5547
Warning: Error in tag: argument is missing, with no default
Stack trace (innermost first):
    52: tag
    51: tags$div
    50: div
    49: mainPanel
    48: sidebarLayout
    47: tag
    46: tags$div
    45: div
    44: tagList
    43: attachDependencies
    42: bootstrapPage
    41: fluidPage
     1: runApp
Error : argument is missing, with no default
```

How do I resolve it? Please help

Answer (score 0):

`renderUI()` can be used to get UI output. An example is given in this link: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html

Comment: Thanks Sahban Tariq. Is it that I have to use renderUI instead of eventReactive()?I am not understanding whether the function written textanalysis in server.r correct?Is it getting called properly?